# Subdivise UITableView layer into layers

Tags: uitableview, calayer, catransform3d

I would like to split my tableview's layer into two layers. Like this I will be able to transform one of them.
How can I manage that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? How do you want to split the table view's layer? You can use my UITableView category in [LTKit](https://github.com/LucasTizma/LTKit) to grab the rects of interest from the table view (the section headers, the sections themselves, all the visible table view cell rects, etc.): https://github.com/LucasTizma/LTKit/blob/master/LTKit/Categories/UITableView%2BLTKAdditions.m

Using this, you can easily grab the table view's layer as an image representation and then split up that image into sublayers you can then transform or animate as I've done here: http://f.cl.ly/items/0s2S101b1E2e3N0D431m/Screen%20Recording%203.mov

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I think your categories can help me. Here a screenshot of Cocktail Flox : http://grab.by/c9Gk